# Socket io: socket.use() doesn't authenticate incoming socket connection

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I was trying to authenticate every incoming sockets on a namespace. I came across [socket level middleware](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-socket-instance/#Socket-middlewares) in the docs. I copied the code sample from there, but it doesn't seem to work for me.
Here is the code:

**`Server Side`**

```js
io.of('/').on('connection', socket => {
  
  socket.use(([event, ...args], next) => {
    console.log('middleware here') // doesn't log anything
    return next(new Error('unauthorized event')) // trying to abort the connection
  })

  socket.on('error', err => {
    if (err && err.message === 'unauthorized event') {
      console.log('here') // doesn't log anything
      socket.disconnect()
    }
  })

  console.log('disconnected:' socket.disconnected) // logs 'false', socket doesn't disconnect

})
```

On the **`client`** side, I tried to add a [catch all listener](https://socket.io/docs/v4/listening-to-events/#Catch-all-listeners)

```js
const socket = io('/')

socket.onAny((eventName, ...args) => {
  console.log('here') //doesn't log anything
});

socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log(socket) //logs the socket
})
```

Why I can't get it work the way doc has stated?